# Info Agent's SNMP

Tags: snmp

I Have some questions:

In in my system (es. windows), have many DLL extension agent attached with snmp service

When a request comes to the service snmp "Snmp.exe" it sends the request to all agents or only one?

How do I know which of them can answer the request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main agent's job is to handle registrations for SNMP and each DLL will register the information it is able to serve.  The information in SNMP is registered under a tree-structure represented by OIDs.  The agent is smart enough to know which DLL (or subagent) is able to serve up a request based on the incoming OID being asked about.

You might consider reading [RFC2741](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2741.html) which describes the "AgentX" protocol.  Although this talks about the protocol and not a DLL, the fundamental way it works under the hood should be pretty similar.

Comment: +1 I globaly agree Just one thing an AgentX is conceptualy different from the way Microsoft allow mib extensions. An AgentX works in his own process link to main agent by soket. If an error occure in an extension agent the Microsoft SNMP agent just fall.

Comment: Definitely true.  Plugins interact very differently to actually exchange the data.  However, how a main loop decides who to ask is fundamentally the same: they hold a list of registrations and try and figure out how to determine which sub-piece (be it built in code, a subagent, or a plugin) to send the question to.  The AgentX RFC actually describes this architecture fairly well.

Comment: Yes I wrote an AgentX on the top of Net-SNMP, I agree with you the global concept is similar, but the technical result is different. I just wrote the wrapper that allow to know which OIDs are served by a DLL.

Answer (score 1):

@Wes response is OK. Here is just a complement. As discribed in "[How to add an SNMP extension agent to the NT registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128729/en-us)", you can find the DLL extension in the registry entries pointed by the one in :

Windows Server NT4 to Windows Server 2003 R2 (Workstatio, W2K, XP):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameter\ExtensionAgents
```

Begining Windows 2008 (Vista) :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SNMP\Parameters\ExtensionAgents
```

Each DLL expose `SnmpExtensionInit` function which report the supportedView as an OID.

```
BOOL WINAPI SnmpExtensionInit (DWORD dwTimeZeroReference,
                               HANDLE *hPollForTrapEvent,
                               AsnObjectIdentifier *supportedView);
```

I write a wrapper program that just load the DLL and call the function just to report the response, you can download and try [slxSNMPInfo](http://www.silogix.fr/Outils/slxsnmpinfo.aspx) if you want. Sorry the site is in french, but the strings in the EXE files are in english.

[image]